# Django rest framework disable field update after condition

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF and I need to disable the update of a field if a condition on the same model is respected.

example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()
    checkfield = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

`text` can be modified unless `checkfield` is `True`.

So `if Foo.checkfield is True` `Foo.text` cannot be modified via DRF API.
What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Advanced serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#advanced-serializer-usage) will do what you want.

Just create your custom serializer and in your view, check the value of checkfield. If it's true, pass it the text argument so it enables the field in the serializer.

Btw, since you only need one fixed extra field to be removed or added, instead of passing the fields argument as in the example, you can pass it something like `enable_text=checkfield` and then add the text field to the 'fields' variable in your serializer according to the value of 'checkfield'.

**update to clarify:**

Define your serializer without the text field. Then in your ModelViewSet, override the update method so you get the serializer this way (I think the get_serializer() method does not allow to pass extra args):

YourSerializer(object, enable_text=True)

And, inside your serializer **init** method, when 'enable_text' is True, you add the text field to the self.fields attribute.

I haven't tested if this works but I think it is the way to go.

### **Edit with snippet and modification**

I've been digging a bit with what I explained and turned out it is a bit messy for the simple modification you are trying to do. What I've come up with is just to override the update method in your ViewSet. Here is the code:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from models import Test, TestSerializer


class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        self.object = self.get_object_or_none()

        if 'enable_text' in request.DATA and request.DATA['enable_text'] == True:
            request.DATA['text'] = self.object.text
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object, data=request.DATA,
                                         files=request.FILES, partial=partial)

        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        try:
            self.pre_save(serializer.object)
        except ValidationError as err:
            # full_clean on model instance may be called in pre_save,
            # so we have to handle eventual errors.
            return Response(err.message_dict, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if self.object is None:
            self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
            self.post_save(self.object, created=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        self.object = serializer.save(force_update=True)
        self.post_save(self.object, created=False)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This code is taken from the rest_framework source code for the UpdateMixin. Take special attention at lines `if 'enable_text' in request.DATA and...` and `request.DATA['text'] = self.object.text`. Those are the ones allowing you to do the funcionality you need. Basically:

- If you send the enable_text with True along with text, text will be modified.
- If you send the enable_text with False along with text, it will be ignored.

Note that this code only takes into account the value of enable_text passed in the current request. You maybe want also that if enable_text is not in the current request, to check the value of enable_text in the `self.object` (which is the database instance itself).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @djangozone. Since I use class based views (`ModelViewSet`), where do you suggest to check the value of `checkfield`? inside the function `get_serializer_class` or somewhere else?

Comment: thanks again. Sorry, I'm a bit confused. May you write down a small snippet?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simpler solution. Hope it is clear now.